# Find a counterexample of complex exponents

Tags: complex-numbers, examples-counterexamples

I am looking to find a counterexample for the equation $e^{z_{1}z_{2}}=(e^{z_{1}})^{z_{2}}$. Obviously this is wrong due to the choice of branch of multivalued complex function can be different. However, I am troubled in finding one counterexample for it. Choosing $z_{1}=z_{2}$ a same complex number seems easier, but which number can be chosen?

By the way I have tried $z_{1}=z_{2}=\text{Log}(i)$.

*EDITTED after Joe's comment:*

Defining $z^w$ where $z$ and $w$ are both complex numbers.

\begin{equation}
z^w=e^{w\text{Log}(z)}=e^{w(\text{Log}\vert z\vert+i\text{Arg}(z))}
\end{equation}
Here, we choose the principal branch, and the principal argument is $(-\pi,\pi]$.

Comment: Something like that  $e^{-2\pi}=e^{2\pi i^2}= (e^{2\pi i})^i =1^i=1$?

Comment: @Gerd That's a good one, great.

Comment: @CunyiNan: There are differing conventions for how to define $z^w$ when $z$ and $w$ are complex numbers (and $z\neq 0)$. One convention is to define $z^w$ as the *set* of numbers $\exp(wl)$, where $l$ is a logarithm of $z$ (i.e. $l$ is a complex number satisfying $\exp(l)=z)$. If that is the definition you are using, then I suggest you edit your question to be explicit about this. There are certainly other definitions which allow us to define $z^w$ in a single-valued way.

Comment: @Joe I used the definition of $\text{exp}$ as that in real number.

Comment: @CunyiNan: There is no ambiguity about how $\exp:\mathbb C\to\mathbb C$ should be defined. The issue is with how $z^w$ should be defined: the ambiguity arises because the complex exponential function is not injective. (It does not quite make sense to say "I used the definition of $\exp$ as that in real number", since in real analysis, $\exp$ is nearly always interpreted as a function $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$, which is not what you want here.)

Comment: @Joe Define $z^{w}=\text{exp}(w\text{Log}(z))$ as this, here $\text{Log}(z)=\text{Log}\vert z\vert+i\text{Arg}(z)$, i.e. the principal branch.

Comment: @CunyiNan: Thanks for clarifying. Unfortunately, there are also differing conventions for how to define $\operatorname{Arg}$, so I suggest you specify whether you intend the argument to be in $(-\pi,\pi]$ or in $[0,2\pi)$ when you edit your question.

Comment: @CunyiNan: I've edited my answer again to correct a small error (the complex exponential is *never* zero), and I've come up with a slightly simpler counter-example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For all $z_1,z_2\in\mathbb C$,
$\DeclareMathOperator{\Log}{Log}$
\begin{align}
\exp(z_1z_2)=\exp(z_1)^{z_2}&\iff \exp(z_1z_2)=\exp(z_2\Log(\exp(z_1)) \\[5pt]
&\iff \exists n\in\mathbb Z: z_1z_2=z_2\Log(\exp(z_1))+2\pi in \, .
\end{align}
Hence, if $\Log(\exp(z_1))=z_1$, then it *is* true that $\exp(z_1z_2)=\exp(z_1)^{z_2}$. So to find a counter-example, we need to find a $z_1$ for which this does not hold. For instance, if we let $z_1=2\pi i$, then
\begin{align}
\exp(z_1z_2)=\exp(z_1)^{z_2}&\iff \exists n\in \mathbb Z:(2\pi i)z_2=2\pi i n \\[5pt]
&\iff z_2\in\mathbb Z \, .
\end{align}
Now let $z_2$ be a non-integer. Then, $\exp(z_1z_2)\neq\exp(z_1)^{z_2}$.